# Let $a,b,c >0$ Prove the inequality $\displaystyle{\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+1}+\frac{c}{c+1}+\frac{1}{a+b+c+1} \geq 1}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c >0$

Prove the inequality $\displaystyle{\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+1}+\frac{c}{c+1}+\frac{1}{a+b+c+1} \geq 1}$

I dont even know where to begin.

Only interested in hints (not solution)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint :

$$\frac{a}{a+1} > \frac{a}{a+b+c+1}$$

$$\frac{b}{b+1} > \frac{b}{a+b+c+1}$$

$$\frac{c}{c+1} > \frac{c}{a+b+c+1}$$

Comment: Duh! I get it now

Comment: The whole expression is $> \frac{a+b+c+1}{a+b+c+1} = 1$

Answer (score 3):

We have $a+1\leq a+b+c+1$, $b+1\leq a+b+c+1$ and $c+1\leq a+b+c+1$ so $\frac 1{x+1}\geq \frac 1{1+a+b+c}$ where $x=a,b$ or $c$. Now multiply by $x$ to get $\frac x{x+1}\geq \frac x{1+a+b+c}$ and sum.

Comment: If $a+1 \geq a+b+c+1$ doesn't that mean $b+c \leq 0$?

Comment: Sorry I reversed the inequalities, now I think it's correct.